# Coalesce values from different properties into a single array with MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to figure out if there's a combination of aggregation operators that would result, given input documents similar to this:

```
[
 { field1: 1, field2: 2 },
 { field1: 2, field2: 3 }
]
```

in an output document with a single array field whose elements are the distinct values of fields `field1` and `field2` of the input documents, in this example:

```
{ result: [1,2,3] }
```

I tried these so far:

- `$addToSet`, but it doesn't seem to support multiple arguments , i.e. doesn't allow to `$addToSet` from more than one property in the same document
- `$project` to project `field1` and `field2` into a resulting array field that I could then `$unwind` and then `$addToSet`, but projecting two (or more) properties into an array doesn't seem to be supported either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on a right track with [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/), but as you noticed you can't create a set from multiple fields. You can combine multiple arrays by using [$setUnion](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) operator. You need to add an additional $project into your aggregation pipeline.

Using MongoDB shell:

```js
db.coll.aggregate([
    // group to create sets
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "a": { "$addToSet": "$a" },
        "b": { "$addToSet": "$b" }
    }},
    // project to merge the arrays
    { "$project": { 
        "result": { "$setUnion": [ "$a", "$b" ] }
    }}
]);
```